# React Native - style responsiveness for different screen sizes

Tags: react-native

We are building an app which is going to run on multiple devices (iOS, Android) and therefore on many screen sizes. After reading about [PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html) it still doesn't seem as if there is a magic solution to scale automatically all style values according to the different screen sizes.

The only solution I could think of was to override the `Stylesheet` class to automatically scale all sizes according to the current screen size. For example:

```
import {StyleSheet} from ‘react-native’;
import { Dimensions, Platform, PixelRatio } from ‘react-native’;

const {
    width,
    height
} = Dimensions.get(‘window’);

const scale = width / 320;

const ratioKeys = {
    fontSize: true,
    paddingHorizontal: true,
    paddingVertical: true,
    paddingTop: true,
    paddingLeft: true,
    paddingRight: true,
    paddingBottom: true,
    padding: true,
    marginHorizontal: true,
    marginVertical: true,
    marginTop: true,
    marginRight: true,
    marginLeft: true,
    marginBottom: true,
    margin: true,
    width: true,
    height: true,
    lineHeight: true,
}

// automatically scale specific keys (specified above) according to the screen size
const parseKey = (key, value) => {

   if (ratioKeys[key]) {
        value = value * scale;
    }

   return value;
}

export const parseStyle = (style) => {
    console.log(‘style -> ’, style);
    return Object.keys(style).reduce((output, key) => {
        output[key] = parseKey(key, style[key]);
        return output;
    }, {});
}

const parseStyleSheet = (styles) => {
    console.log(‘styles -> ’, styles);
    return Object.keys(styles).reduce((output, key) => {
       output[key] = parseStyle(styles[key]);
       return output;
    }, {});
}

export default {
    create: (style) => {
        return StyleSheet.create(parseStyleSheet(style));
    }
}
```

It seems pretty strange that this wouldn't actually be supported out of the box, so I guess I am missing something?

Comment: It definitely is not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this library as a solution, it supports media queries, and we may eventually use it if we feel we need more customization than flexbox. I've seen it in action and it looks like it might address some of your needs: https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet